# What does "Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()" mean?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, toolkit

I got three rather small questions so I'd like to ask them all in one thread here.

1- What does `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()` mean?

2- What does `g.dispose()` do? (`g` is a `Graphics` object).

3- What does this: `setDoubleBuffered(true)` mean?

All of the above happen in a class extending JPanel.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the JavaDocs for those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`sync()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync%28%29) - sunchronizes the graphics state
- [`dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync%28%29) - Disposes of this graphics context and releases any system resources that it is using. A Graphics object cannot be used after disposehas been called.
- [`setDoubleBuffered()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29) - Sets whether this component should use a buffer to paint. If set to true, all the drawing from this component will be done in an offscreen painting buffer. The offscreen painting buffer will the be copied onto the screen. If a Component is buffered and one of its ancestor is also buffered, the ancestor buffer will be used.

---

Follow the links. You really need to learn how to search and read documentation.

Here's a link to the [Documentation homepage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/). Anytime you need to ask a question like this, go to this page first, and search.

Comment: haha as if "Synchronizes this toolkit's graphics state." would explain what .sync() really does ...

Comment: Can't say this answer helped me /: When is this needed? I haven't had any problems excluding it from my code, so when is this needed?

Comment: Me either. "Su[sic]nchronizes the graphics state" with _what_, exactly? And what _is_ the "graphics state?" France? Because of those cartoons?